# java command to display all XX options

Tags: java

In java the to display all `print help on non-standard options` we use

```
java -X
```

is there any java option that display all non standard options of XX options like

```
-XX:-AllowUserSignalHandlers
-XX:-DisableExplicitGC
..........
etc
```

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but [here](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html) is a seemingly complete list.